# "Curt with someone" or "curt to someone"?

Tags: prepositions, adjectives

Which preposituon do I use with the adjective *curt* when I want to say that someone was briefly rude to someone? For example:

> The boss was curt **with**/**to** me this morning.

I checked a few dictionaries, but I couldn't find examples neither with *with* nor with *to*. I also checked Ngram Viewer, but it interprets *curt* as a name. Is it even correct to use *curt* with *with* or *to* in the first place.

Comment: *Curt* licenses both *with* and *to*. The former is more popular.

Comment: Yes, “curt with me” is certainly the best (most idiomatic) way to use “curt” in this context. There seems to be no real logic supporting this preference. We say, “He was rude TO me.” and yet we prefer to say, “He was curt WITH me.”  This sort of idiomatic preference is just something learners have to pick up as they go.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie that is actually a very good comment, why not post it as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, “curt with me” is certainly the best (most idiomatic) way to use “curt” in this context.

There seems to be no real logic supporting this preference. We say, “He was rude TO me.” and yet we prefer to say, “He was curt WITH me.”

This sort of idiomatic preference is just something learners have to pick up as they go, particularly so with prepositions.